# Delphi Webcam Simple Program

Tags: delphi, webcam

Can anyone help me to create a simple viewing of cam using just a simple TVideo component in delphi having a vid size of 160x120 only as default (no resize). Just a simple one. Please. Badly needed for my new project.

thanks.

Comment: What `TVideo` component are you using? What have you tried so far that isn't working, and what is the specific problem you're having with your code? This is not a "please write my code for me" site - for that you need something like [RentaCoder](http://rentacoder.com) or the equivalent. We're all willing to help solve your problem, but you need to show some effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to do it , I couldn't understand what do you mean by TVideo component but my solution can show image on a paintbox(any TCanvas)

use

http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample/DirectXDelphiWebcamCapture.rar

this is a directX conversion to pascal made by michael@grizzlymotion.com

add VSample.pas and VFrames.pas to your project

```
uses  VFrames;

procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
cam:TVideoImage;
strlst:TStringList;
begin

   strlst := TStringList.Create ;

   cam := TVideoImage.Create;
   cam.GetListOfDevices(strlst);

   cam.SetDisplayCanvas(PaintBox1.Canvas);
   cam.VideoStart(strlst.Strings[0])    ;//specify your cam by number
end;
```

Comment: can i have another question? how can i set my video size from default of 640x360 in 160x120 video size?? please help

Comment: @Tony http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108973/delphi-webcam-simple-program-video-size

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what TVideo is, but if you can use another component, for non-commercial projects, the Mitov Video library is **free**.  It works with DirectX video, which is what most (all?) webcams use. It comes with excellent example programs, including one that plays back videos.

You can accomplish your goal with almost no programming. You simply drag and drop his components and connect them in his GUI component editor (named OpenWire)in the IDE.

We have used their components for years and are very happy with them.  Highly recommended.

They also have great real-time plotting and audio processing tools that all work together with threading built-in to make it fast, fast, fast.

http://www.mitov.com/.