# Change resolution of  Webcam video using Delphi program

Tags: delphi, webcam

How do I change the size of the webcam from (640x360) as default in `VFrames` into a (160x120) as the new default.

I'm using [`this component`](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample/DirectXDelphiWebcamCapture.rar?attredirects=0&d=1) found on [`this page`](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample).

Comment: The preferred style here is not to ramble, but get to the point. I edited your question for you.  Think of the future people who might have the same question and can find your question and answer better if you don't ramble.

Comment: Please add the name of the delphi component you're using and a link to its source or this question becomes almost useless to others.

Comment: Is it this component? http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a predefined method in VFrames

```
var
  cam:TVideoImage;
  camlist:TStringList;
  reslist:TStringList;
  vp:TVideoProperty;
begin

   camlist := TStringList.Create ;
   reslist :=TStringList.Create;

   cam := TVideoImage.Create;
   cam.GetListOfDevices(camlist);

   cam.SetDisplayCanvas(PaintBox1.Canvas);

   cam.VideoStart(camlist.Strings[0])    ;

   // important 

   cam.GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes(reslist);
   ListBox1.Items := reslist;
   cam.SetResolutionByIndex(0);

   //specify your resolution by index using listbox index
   //this will not only lists resolutions but also other features available , so be careful when selecting the index
end;
```

make sure that `GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes` and `SetResolutionByIndex` are executed after the video has started to play

Comment: thanks you. you really helped me a lot.. but ders something in error appears if i will chose another devices (my cboVideoDevices will create 3 selections and one of them is Google Camera Adapter(0)).. if i will going to chose that one an error will occur "ACCESS VIOLATION on FUNCTION TVideoSample.SetVideoSizeByListIndex(ListIndex: integer): HResult; on line 1160 in VSample". The ListIndex itself is the error, 

FYI: I dunno why google camera adapter(0) and adapter(1) were listed in my cboVideoDevices. Please help me again. Thanks

Comment: @tony , This is not a programming mistake , the list (GetListOfDevices) will show you whatever drivers available in the system (eg:once you may have installed a google driver). I will post you another answer if possible.

Comment: Is there any other way that if i am going to chose that google camera driver or any driver that don't have a camera, it will just pop up or something like won't call the videoStart function in VFrames? i mean a trapping. But really,, thanks a lot. I knw i asked u so many times.

Comment: Please tell me why do you want 120 * 160 , so i can help you

Comment: because my boss only wanted to view the camera if its is working on the program launch b4 everything else,,,

Comment: What is the name of the component being used here? This answer is only of limited use because the OP didn't even state what third party code he's using.

Comment: You really made my day man. Thank you so much, I was trying to figure it out for so long.

Answer (score 0):

in this answer i am using bitmap image.

this will be slightly slower than the previous (but hard to notice)

We are going to get the image on every timer tick (eg interval = 100), assign it to our image box then going to modify our size , no matter what is the default resolution is it will get the default size image(eg: 640 * 480) and in the image box we are going to change the size.

```
uses
  ....
  VFrames;

var
 ....
  cam:TVideoImage;

implementation

 procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  cam := TVideoImage.Create;

  image1.stretch := true ;
  image1.height := 120 ;
  image1.width := 160 ;

end;

 procedure TForm6.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   cam.GetBitmap(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
 end;

 procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   camlist:TStringList;
 begin

   camlist := TStringList.Create ;

   cam := TVideoImage.Create;
   cam.GetListOfDevices(camlist);

   cam.VideoStart(camlist.Strings[0])    ;

end;
```

Comment: thnks for this wonderful code but about the size of the camera, its already in 160x120.. my problem now is this, when i clicked the GOOGLE ADOPTER(1) and (0) i will be sent to the VSample codes and get the access violation error.

Comment: im sory about the upvote..i stil have 5 reputations since it is my first day signing up on this site. but don't worry,, if i can upvote,, definitely i will be one of ur avid voters...

Comment: is there any physical camera respective to google adopter(1) ,

Comment: nope. not at all. i guess this is from the facebook video chat thing.

Comment: OK ,then whenever you use cam.VideoStart(camlist.Strings[0]) ; nest it inside a try except block , eg: if you are using a loop to go through all the cams , try except block will ignore all the invalid cams in that list

Comment: i have to go,, thank you for your time. I'll just deal it tomorrow i guess. out from office THANKKKSSS A LOTTTTTT!

Comment: b d way,, can u elaborate more about the try except block? or something like a code one.. coz i never used it b4.. i was once a web developer then now transfered in DELPHI team.. so hard for me.. again thank you.

Comment: @Tony please post that specific issue as another post so i can help you with some extra info , I can't answer here it will be violating stack-overflow rule