# delphi webcam photo on a Timage/Tbitmap

Tags: delphi, winapi, bitmap, webcam

i'm using this code to take a photo from webcam:

```
if hWndC <> 0 then
  begin
    SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0,
      longint(StringToPAnsiChar('C:\Test.bmp')));
  end;
```

this code will save the photo, how can i take this photo without pass throug a file and store it directly to a Tbitmap or Timage?

sorry for my bad english. thanks in advance

Comment: This question has been asked here already, use search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Video For Windows (FVW) and/or DirectX for such work.
I successfully use code from michael@grizzlymotion.com (VFrames.pas and FSample.pas) which are available from http://siapen.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/webcam/Common/
I use this code with XE4 using DirectX headers provided by XE4.
This article may be useful to: [Delphi Webcam Simple Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106706/delphi-webcam-simple-program)