# Mitov VideoLab camera controls

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi and [Mitov VideoLab 7.0](http://www.mitov.com/faqs/videolab#overview).

I have a CMOS camera that is hooked to a microscope. When I take pictures I need to go to a white spot and correct the white balance. For that I need to use the cameras own control panel. This panel also comes with some other stuff like setting resolution.

Using Delphi XE3 and Videolab 7.

How can I show the camera controls in my Delphi app?

Comment: Camera controls... as in a 'take photo' button, or playback (play/pause buttons), or...? Which version of Delphi and which component in VideoLab are you using specifically?

Comment: Hi,no no let me explain: I have a CMOS camera that is hooked to a microscope. When  I take pictures I need to go to a white spot and correct the white balance. For that I need to use the cameras own control panel. It also comes with some other stuff like setting resolutions. etc..etc. Using XE3 and Videolab 7

Comment: I haven't used Mitov's software, but this seems a different issue all together. Do you have software from your camera running on your PC? It seems like you have to access that software from your Delphi app. Does that software have a programming interface that you can talk with? Please edit your question and update it with this information ('a CMOS camera' is insufficient info).

Comment: VideoLab has lots of color plugins / components and some googling showed [this white balance property belonging to a capture component](http://www.mitov.com/wiki/index.php?title=Property_VLDSCapture.TVLDSAdjustment.WhiteBalance) - why not use that? Chances are there's a way to calculate the degrees from a "white" spot easily too.

Answer (score 0):

> For that I need to use the cameras own control panel. 
>   You don't explain if that control panel is camera's or Videlab's.
>   I will assume you refer that CP is generated by camera's software (driver).
>   So, here is the answer:

If you are lucky and the producer offers also an OCX you can import it in Delphi as then easily access the camera.

Check driver's folder. See if there are any OCX files there
Check producer's the web site
Ask the producer (and hope it will answer)

If there are no OCX files you might still be able to access the camera BUT won't be easy. You can use the camera's driver (DLL) files. But that involves some hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everybody I have solved my issue the following way:

Instead of using Mitov videoLab (btw its a great plug in) I used Vframes found here on StackOverflow:
[Delphi Webcam Simple Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106706/delphi-webcam-simple-program)

I used this to show my camera controls

Cam.ShowProperty;

where Cam: TVideoImage

Moreover the Vframes lets me show the camera directly into TImage canvas so its very easy to capture and save to disk or database.

adotable1.FieldByName('pic').Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);

Where pic is defined as image (im using MSSql Express).
To show the image back I use DBImage linked to the pic field..works like a charm.